# Help with ASP.NET ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource, detailsview

I have a User object with a Load method that takes in a `UserId` parameter and loads that users data to the objects member variables.

Now what I'd like to do is load this data to a `DetailsView` control using an `ObjectDataSource`, but I'm stumped as to how.

First of all, I'm not sure I've got the code set up properly to pass the parameter (UserID) to the `SelectMethod (cUser.Load)`. Secondly, I don't know how I can load this data to the `DetailsView` since I'm not actually returning the results from the `Load` method, I'm simply loading the object with the data...here's my code..

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvUsers" DataKeyNames="UserID" BackColor="#eeeeee"     Width="85%"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana"
                    Font-Size="10pt" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                    OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="IndexChanged" >
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White"
                   Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="yellow" ForeColor="blue" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" />
                   <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2"
                             CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'
                             CommandName="Select" runat="server">
                             Select</asp:LinkButton>
                         </ItemTemplate>     
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"     />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"
                             CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'
                             CommandName="Delete" runat="server">
                             Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
              </asp:GridView><br /><br />
              <asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="dvUser"     DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AutoGenerateRows="False" Width="85%"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="UserID" >
                  <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Birthdate" HeaderText="Birthdate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Apt" HeaderText="Apt" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNum" HeaderText="PhoneNum" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ynAdminUser" HeaderText="ynAdminUser" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowEditButton="True"     ShowInsertButton="True" />
>
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1"
                    runat="server" SelectMethod="Load" TypeName="cUser">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvUsers" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="iUserID" Type="int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve?  if so, can you please give examples with the explanation?

Very much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: My friend, you are referring to ASP.NET and not ASP, it's a different world :) I've edited for you.

Comment: very true, posted in haste...thanks for the correction

Comment: No prob, formatted your question for you further :P

Comment: great, thanks again!  Any chance you can answer it as well? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check this tutorial for detail help....

[Master/Detail Using a Selectable Master GridView with a Details DetailView](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/data-access/tutorial-10-cs.aspx)